# how to switch between API in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask

python 3.x

I have 2 APIs which of them is used to detect a object.
I want to switch between APIs when the results change

For example:

x.x.x.200:7000/obj --- 1st api 
this api returns a result but fails in some case (result none) so then i want to switch to another api meanwhile 
x.x.x.300:8000/obj -- 2nd Api

How will i Switch between APIs?

Comment: Check if api1 returns None and then use api2

Comment: That's what I mentioned in my question. I need a more specific answer or explanation.

Comment: `if api1.failedFunction() == None: api2.doIt()`